# xpages - "runonserver" creates an "error" but continues - why?

Tags: xpages

I am getting this error: An error occurred while updating some of the page.  Unable to load http://localhost/........./xOrderForm.xsp?documentId-570C...44AF&actioneditDocument&$$ajaxid=%40none status: 0

I'm calling an agent to compute some pdf stuff then email.  I don't have the pdf stuff in the agent yet but an example email.  I get this error on a banner in my browser but the email still sends.  How can I get the banner to stop displaying?  Here is the code I'm using in javascript and LS.

Javascript:

```
var ag = database.getAgent("agEmailInvoice");
var vRet = ag.runOnServer(document1.getNoteID());
```

Lotuscript:

```
Dim s As New NotesSession
Dim agent As NotesAgent
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim doc As NotesDocument

Set db = s.CurrentDatabase
Set agent = s.CurrentAgent

REM Get document used for passing data
Set doc = db.GetDocumentByID(agent.ParameterDocID)
REM Send mail containing passed data

Dim memo As New NotesDocument(db)
memo.Form = "Memo"
memo.SendTo = "abc@xyz.com"
memo.Subject = "Message from LotusScript agent"
memo.Body = "The agent was started by "
Call memo.Send(False)
```

Comment: The docID that is being passed is: 19C2  Why isn't the full ID getting sent?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  I indicated "No Update" on the button since I was simply calling the agent to send the message and returning to the previous page.  I changed it to "Full Update" and the message went away and the agent executed.  Thank you for all your consideration everyone.